# Dotnet Core - Entity Framework - What do the empty curly brackets mean in this context and what's the result

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I recently read [THIS](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/5518/multi-tenant-asp-net-core-5---implementing-database-per-tenant-strategy) post on "Implementing database per tenant strategy" by G Pelpman.

It deals with connecting to multiple databases and uses a tenant to create a connection string.

The part I am confused about and what it allows is the following registering of services.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MultitenantDbContext>(o => { });

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddTransient<ITenantProvider, DummyTenantProvider>();
}
```

In particular,

```
services.AddDbContext<MultitenantDbContext>(o => { });
```

Whats the reason for using `(o => { });`?

How does it help in connecting to multiple databases?

Comment: It is an empty action delegate. That action delegate can be removed altogether  if no setup is going to be done in startup ie `services.AddDbContext<MultitenantDbContext>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**services.AddDbContext** receives an **Action** *(Action)* as a parameter...
in this case, as said in the very post you shared **"Implementing database per tenant strategy"**, no conections will be provided by **ConfigureServices()**, so an empty Action is passed to **services.AddDbContext()** to fullfil the **optionsAction** param...
Connections will be further provided based on the Tenant defined on **DbContextOptionsBuilder._tenant**